# Why IE Developer Tools seems to be more descriptive than FireBug in this example?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug, developer-tools

When I call this line:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,"innerHTML")
```

For **FireBug** it **returns**:

```
>>> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,"innerHTML")
```

where for IE, **Developer Tools** it **returns**:

```
>> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,"innerHTML") 
{
    get :  function innerHTML() {     [native code] } ,
    set :  function innerHTML() {     [native code] } ,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : true
}
```

Do you know why it is different? Why IE Dev. Tools seems to be more descriptive than FireBug for this case?

Comment: Not sure, but the FF4 web console shows the full details, so it's probably a Firebug problem (a Firebugbug?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the way Firebug runs your input generates an exception, which is then in turn hidden by Firebug. Try running:

```
try { Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,"innerHTML") } catch (ex) { console.log(ex); }
```

And you'll see what I mean. As @lonesomeday suggested, try using the web console instead.

Comment: But why it throws an exception then?

Comment: The short answer is "because Firebug is highly magical and by extension volatile when it comes to displaying objects, and evaluates your JS in a strange way". If you feed it things which throw exceptions when poked in weird places, it may break. You could actually probably file a bug about this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The right place to report it is where by the way? can you provide the url?

Comment: Thanks! I have submitted the issue.