# how to check if charCodeAt() is configurable

Tags: javascript, firebug, enumerable, configurable

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262132/why-ie-developer-tools-seems-to-be-more-descriptive-than-firebug-in-this-example) it is described how to check if `innerHTML` property is configurable and enumerable using Firebug/FF Web Console.
How can I check the same for `charCodeAt` function? `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,"charCodeAt")`
return `undefined`.

Comment: It says that it doesn't work in Firebug there. Make sure you are using the FF web console and not firebug

Answer (score 4):

The [`.charCodeAt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) belongs to [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), not to `HTMLElement`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String.prototype,"charCodeAt")
```

Comment: It's directly on `String`, instead of `String.prototype`.

Comment: @amnotiam pretty sure it's in the prototype :P You are thinking `fromCharCode`

Comment: @amnotiam - Are you sure? When I [try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/7KPzq/) with `String.prototype` it works but `String` doesn't. (Testing in Chrome.)

Comment: @Esailija, nnnnnn: You're right. Though in Firefox it's also on `String`. +1

Comment: Yeah, that's nonstandard. Firefox also adds Array.forEach and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `charCodeAt` is not a method of `HTMLElement`, it's a method in the `String`-Object (or rather its prototype)

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String.prototype,"charCodeAt")
```

Comment: @amnotiam it lies in the prototype, checking only on `String` returns undefined in Chrome for example